# How to SSH second user to Linux server (CentOS)

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I connect to my DigitalOcean droplet (linux CentOS server) through SSH with root user. It's workin fine without any problem. But when I try to connect to my server through second non root user it gives me an error:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

This is my steps to setup access for second user:

- `adduser seconduser` - create second user on Server (the name of a new
  user is the same as the name of a user on my local Mac)
- `sudo su - seconduser` - switch to new user
- `cd ~` - go to home dir
- `mkdir .ssh` - create new .ssh
- `chmod 700 .ssh` - setup rwe permission for dir
- `touch .ssh/authorized_keys` - create file
- `chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys` - setup rw permission for open key
  file
- `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub` - copy my open key from my local mac
- `vim .ssh/authorized_keys` - paste it in file on server

Then I try to connect, like this:

- `ssh seconduser@111.111.111.111`

and it gives me an error.

I tried to solve it by changing ssh folder from home\ to etc\ like in this answer:https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1932058 but it doesn't help.

Also I double check my open key (it's the same and root is workin with this key).

Also I checked permissions on file and dir on my local Mac:
~/.ssh/id_* permissions is 600

Also I checked /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. There are:

```
RSAAuthentication yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

So, what have I doing wrong? It's my second day with this trouble.
Please help!

Comment: Check `/var/log/auth.log`, it may give you clues.

Comment: You forgot to add option `-i /path/to/your/private.key` in `ssh` command